# Multiple titles for a single question

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Often when a question comes to Stack Overflow, it gets closed and deleted. It is good in some sense that it reduces the number of duplicates, but it is also a concern that different users use different question titles or Google search queries so as to say to search for an existing answer.

If the question title could be multiple then many differently worded question with same answer would be easier to search. I know maybe not someone may point out that we can choose the best title, but I don't thing there is any "best" way to represent a things. People think differently. Their choice of words are different though they might mean the same.

So, maybe stealing titles from duplicated answers and just using a list of titles for the answer and maybe reward the person with a few reps or maybe nothing, up to you.

Comment: _"So, maybe stealing titles from duplicated answers and just using a list of titles for the answer and maybe reward the person with a few reps or maybe nothing, up to you."_ Well, I prefer to close questions as a duplicate, and maybe even edit the duplicate banner to add more duplicate links. I believe this is enough, and should even affect google search (it does as far as I experienced). I wouldn't mind to get rep for these efforts though.

Comment: Well I was searching for a pandas question recently where the question was somewhat like how to do reverse of break a column with a list into different columns. Well another way to say this would be how to do reverse explode. I found the answer on Gitter after saying reverse explode.

Comment: Note that here on Meta Stack Exchange, on questions requesting new features, voting [is used to signify agreement or disagreement with a given proposal](/help/whats-meta), so if your question gets downvoted, it may just mean that people disagree with your proposal, not necessarily that your question is bad for the site.

Comment: yes I get it now @SonictheMaskedWerehog

Comment: Do linked duplicates as sign-posts not already accomplish this purpose? When you search for something and come up with a duplicate, it acts as a kind of pointer to the "real" answer that's linked.

Comment: I m talking about the deleted ones, if I understood that correctly @zcoop98

Comment: Gotcha, I missed the "and deleted" of your post's first sentence @Vishesh

Comment: @zcoop98 to `Do linked duplicates as sign-posts not already accomplish this purpose? When you search for something and come up with a duplicate, it acts as a kind of pointer to the "real" answer that's linked.` . If you merge the duplicate's answer with the original one, would it reduce the number of duplicate questions in that case? I have seen upvoted duplicates but I do not know the logic of that

Comment: @Vish I'm not sure I fully understand your question; I think the answer depends on whether the duplicate question gets deleted. Sometimes a merge is done across several duplicates to create a grand-master post specifically designed to point future dupes to, [which is called a canonical question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291994/11047824).

Comment: Thanks @zcoop98 . I didn't know that.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for more than one title since there are already tags.

If a question has several "sides", just put more tags. If there are more than 5, it means the question is most likely too broad and off topic anyway in Stack Exchange site.

Comment: ok, I just saw that explode was a tag. I should have researched better. Still the problem persists that SO has an answer to my problem and neither the tag or title is not close enough to my search query.

Answer (score 1):

If you have duplicated answers, then you probably have duplicated questions. The solution is to find the best question and close all the others as duplicates of that one, so that people can Google to find whatever question matches their search the best and be redirected to the best answer. A question can even be closed as a duplicate of many questions.

Each duplicate has a banner showing the title of the question(s) it was closed against. For the best questions, which are not closed themselves, the title of some linked questions (including duplicates closed) are also shown on the page, in the linked questions sidebar.

Comment: maybe you are misinterpreting me, I m not saying to "show" a list of titles, I 'm saying to put those titles like in the meta tag(if I know my html). SEO only not crowding the page with list of titles.

Comment: Also there can be a best answer, but not a best way to frame a question. I can give more examples like explode.